# Plotly base values are in percentage

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have table in which one my base values are in percentage

```
ID     TYPE     PERCENTAGE
1      gold         15%
2      silver       71.4%
3      platinum     20%  
4      copper       88.88%
```

But plotly doesn't like that

[image]

Do you know how I could tell him "hey these data are in percentage, please show me a percentage graph"?

Comment: Convert your percentage column to numeric and it will plot correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think plotly is the required answer, so I created it in Plotly. I have converted the percentages in the existing data frame to decimal format. Finally, I set the Y axis display to '%'.

```
import plotly.express as px

df['PERCENTAGE'] = df['PERCENTAGE'].apply(lambda x:float(str(x).strip('%')) / 100)

fig = px.bar(df, x='TYPE', y='PERCENTAGE')
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='%')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: Thanks it's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
df.PERCENTAGE = df.PERCENTAGE.str.replace('%', '') #remove % sign

df.PERCENTAGE = pd.to_numeric(df.PERCENTAGE) #convert to numeric

plt.bar(df.TYPE, df.PERCENTAGE) #plot
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Note you can always check the type of your data with `df.dtypes`

Comment: You're welcome! Can you please consider upvoting my answer (no need to indicate it as the accepted answer, but upvoting it would be nice :)

Comment: Hey, I already did it but " Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." And I have less than 15 reputation since I'm brand new ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I had not seen that indeed. All best!