# Plot percentage in barplot instead of count plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

I have a pandas df that looks like

```
df= { 'review_year' : [2021,2021,2021,2021,2020, 2020], 'sentiment' :['negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive']}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
```

when I run this

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

df= { 'review_year' : [2021,2021,2021,2021,2020, 2020], 'sentiment' :['negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive']}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)

fig = px.bar(df, x="sentiment", color="sentiment", 
  animation_frame="review_year")
fig.show()
```

I get

[image]

In Y axis, instead of the count, I want to see the percentage of 'negative' and 'positive' sentiments for every year.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your questions been asked and answered in a variety of ways. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893937/how-to-create-percentage-stacked-bar-chart-in-plotly), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67418810/how-to-create-100-stacked-bar-charts-in-plotly), or even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408401/plotly-base-values-are-in-percentage).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly base values are in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408401/plotly-base-values-are-in-percentage)